# TFS 2013, unable to perform build with shelveset

Tags: tfs

I have customized buildTemplate and saved it in a shelveset; when I try to build using the saved shelveset  I get warning like this

> Warning: There are other pending changes against the item. for the file in shelveset

the build happens with previous change set.

Build are private as expected but I don't understand that why its ignoring the shelveset?

Comment: Wait, you saved the build template in a shelveset? Or you're using a customized build template to build code changes from a shelveset?

Comment: customized build template is what I am trying to use to build the code so shelveset contain build template only,  this error should clarify what is included in shelveset

Trying to unshelve the shelveset 'XAML'
$/<PATH>/TfvcTemplate.12-OSSBuild.xaml: Warning: There are other pending changes against the item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can't do what you're trying to do. You can't shelve changes to the build template and queue a build to it. When it attempts to unshelve the new template it is already reading the template that exists in the local machine. It then attempts to override the one it is currently using with your shelveset version, resulting in the error.

Comment: You are partially correct;(+1) shelving build template does not build with shelved changes to build template, 

However the warning is still  there even for files for which shelving build is possible.